# Google App Engine, OpenID+OAuth for desktop apps

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, openid, desktop-application

I would appreciate some pointers on how to accomplish what I think the 
gentleman in this thread is doing: http://goo.gl/uIEZk

Specifically, I'm trying to follow the suggestions from here: http://goo.gl/Nkyjv

I have a new AppEngine (Java) site using federated login. Everything 
appears to be working with that setup - I've implemented /_ah/ 
login_required/ and am able to successfully login/logout when 
accessing "secured" URLs in my application.

What I'm not getting (maybe because I'm not understanding something), 
is how to get OAuth working ... my understanding is that I need OAuth 
to provide my desktop application with a long-lived access token that 
it can use. I've read reams of documentation, it seems, but I'm not 
putting it together for some reason.

I have registered my AppEngine application with Google ... I have a 
key/secret and the RSA cert/key from that process. I have no idea how/ 
where to use this ... presumably this is part of the hybrid openid 
+oauth mechanism, but in following the "Implementing OAuth with Federated Login (Hybrid Protocol)" docs from Google -- I'm not 
seeing where/how.

My goal is pretty straightforward ... users install the desktop app, 
which needs to access secured URLs in my app engine app - instead of 
providing username/password in the desktop app, users go to a URL in 
my app engine app ... they login (using any OpenID provider), 
-- authentication/authorization/oauth stuff -- happens, then they get a 
key to enter into the desktop app ... the desktop app turns this 
around and gets the long-lived OAuth token for accessing secured URLs 
in my app engine app.

The -- oauth stuff happens -- bit in the middle is what I'm apparently 
missing ...

Any pointers to more (clear) docs/samples/explanations? Once I have the 'permananet' token(s), my desktop app can use ClientLogin, but it seems like I'm missing a few pieces before that point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you got OpenID functional, which is good. Have you not had any luck with the App Engine OAuth documentation found at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview.html ? Please provide specifics like error tracebacks, example code snippets you're trying, etc.

Comment: Well, it's in this set of documentation that I first start getting confused. Neither my web application (on GAE) nor my desktop application (talking with the GAE app) need access to any _other_ services (like Calendar/Picasa/etc.) - the desktop application needs access to the GAE app only.

So, I haven't actually done anything with the information at that link ... I've tried to get a request token using the OpenID+OAuth hybrid authentication, but adding the oauth attributes to the createLoginURL(..,..,..,attributes) call doesn't do anything.

Do I need to access /_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken ??

Comment: thx for your feedback... we'll take this and pass it to the team and hopefully be able to come up with an article that gives a clearer and more well-documented example of *authorization* (e.g., OAuth/2). keep in mind that this is different from *authentication* (e.g., OpenID).